# New map file with MikTeX

Tags: fonts, miktex

I am new to MikTeX. I have set up a texmf tree and included that into MikTeX (works OK because the style files are found). But the font in that directory cannot be used yet, because the pdftex.map does not have the info from my map file.

I run `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap` (also with `--admin`) and enter (as the only line)

```
Map mymap.map
```

then I run `updmap` (also with `--admin` and `--verbose`), my mapfile gets listed as `Parsing "c:\Path\to\mapfile.map"...`. But pdftex does not work, because it fails with:

```
Trying to make PK font abc8x at 600 DPI...
...
```

When I manually include the map file in first line of my .tex file

```
 \pdfmapfile{+mymap.map}
```

everything is OK.

How do I do without the `\pdfmapfile{...}` line?

Comment: is the map file in a directory where TeX will search for files?

Comment: Yes. It is in the texmf directory that I have added in MikTeX (the one with the style file that gets loaded) below `texmf/fonts/map/dvips/mymap.map` (and also below `pdftex/mymap.map`).

Comment: and you also updated the file name data base? So that `kpsewhich mymap.map` finds the file?

Comment: Assuming that you did run initexmf and updmap *without* the --admin key: Update the FNDB with `initexmf -u`. Run again `updmap --verbose`. Try again your font. If it doesn't work: Check which pdftex.map updmap writes. Check if this it the map file your document use (see end of the log-file). Check if this pdftex.map contains the entries of your map.

Comment: @Herbert: yes, kpsewhich finds the file.

Comment: I have no idea how it works under Windows, but on Linuy I always run `updmap-sys --enable Map=mymap.map`

Comment: @Ulrike. That solved the problem. I have not run `initexmf -u` before (but clicked on the update filename database in the miktex settings (admin)). I am slightly confused, I have to admit.

Comment: I have tried with a clean install: add the texmf tree, run `initexmf --admin --edit-config-file updmap.cfg` and `updmap --admin --verbose` and now it works. Strange.

Comment: @Patrick: no not strange. You have a multi user installation with an admin and a user mode. And in contrast to the widespread prejudice the admin mode is not the more powerful. In general user settings (packages, configurations, map files, texmf trees...) take precedence over the default settings from the admin. What you do in user mode will normally work directly and without problems - but only for this user. What you do in admin mode will work for all user - as long as they don't have personal settings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(Converting Ulrike's comments to an answer)

Assuming that you did run `initexmf` and `updmap` without the `--admin key`: Update the FNDB with `initexmf -u`, run `updmap --verbose` then try again your font. If it doesn't work: Check which `pdftex.map` `updmap` writes. Check if this it the map file your document use (see end of the log-file). Check if this `pdftex.map` contains the entries of your map.

## Explanation

You have a multi user installation with an admin and a user mode. And in contrast to the widespread prejudice the admin mode is not the more powerful. In general, user settings (packages, configurations, map files, texmf trees, ...) take precedence over the default settings from the admin. What you do in user mode will normally work directly and without problems - but only for this user. What you do in admin mode will work for all user - as long as they don't have personal settings. See for more in [Difference between administrative and user mode of MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67712/difference-between-administrative-and-user-mode-of-miktex).

## Note

Exactly the same happens on Unix systems. Running `updmap` and not `updmap-sys` (with superuser privileges) will leave a `pdftex.map` in the user space that will have precedence over the system wide one. This may have undesirable effects in case of an update to the distribution that changes the font subsystem.

## Example

(from http://docs.miktex.org/manual/advanced.html, using problem cited in [Font display error in windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133781/font-display-error-in-windows?lq=1), which produces the error `The mathkerncmssi source file could not be found.`)

1. Run `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap`.
2. Insert the following line at the end of the file (relevant to the font in question):
   `Map sansmathaccent.map`
3. Save the file and close the editor.
4. Run `initexmf --mkmaps` to rebuild the font map files.

---

For a general guidance see [Manual font installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes This is a CW answer made up by me from comments: feel free to edit!