# beamer over miktex 2.9 is not working with math environment

Tags: beamer, math-mode, packages

I have this problem where I can't built slide documents with beamer every time I include a math environment as simple as `$\mu = A$`. The log file posts this message at the end:

```
!pdfTeX error: miktex-pdftex.exe (file mathkerncmssi10): Font mathkerncmssi10 a
t 657 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I understand that the file (`mathkerncmssi10`) that is apparently missing is part of the package `sansmathaccent`, but the package is already there and updated.

This is driving me crazy, I would appreciate any help.

---

Sure, I tried this with several examples. I can post this one

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\title[Make a LaTeX presentation using Beamer]{Introduction  to Beamer\\How to make a presentation with LaTeX?}
\author{Nadir Soualem -- Astozzia}
\institute{Math-linux.com}
\date{Jule 13, 2007}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
This is a short introduction to Beamer class.
$\mu=A$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

By the way, it turns out that I just tried this one in another PC and works fine.

Comment: This looks like a defective installation. I'd be tempted to run the MiKTeX update wizard: do it both in 'admin' and 'normal user' modes to make sure you get everything.

Comment: Your pdftex.map-file hasn't been updated. Normally this happens if you have a local pdftex.map (in your user profile) created e.g. by an on-the-fly installation. In such cases you must run `updmap` to update the map if you install a font.

Comment: I don't understand why this topic has been closed. I had the same problem and @UlrikeFischer's solution has rescued me.

Comment: Can someone with enough privileges vote to reopen? I had the same problem too, solved running C:\Pragram Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\updmap.exe, thanks @UlrikeFischer

Comment: It solved my problem too @Oriol

Comment: Did you try running LyX as administrator?

Answer (score 13):

Your `pdftex.map`-file hasn't been updated. Normally this happens if you have a local `pdftex.map` (in your user profile) created e.g. by an on-the-fly installation. In such cases you must run `updmap` to update the map if you install a font.

Comment: I have the problem cited by the OP, and unfortunately, your suggested fix does not resolve it.  I did locate two files: `xpdftex_ndl14.map` and `xpdftex_dl14` that could be culprits, I suppose.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22453/new-map-file-with-miktex/28811#28811) (especially the **Example** section).

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me when I had a similar error.

Simply navigate to your miktex bin directory (e.g. `c:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\`) and execute the commands below:

- `initexmf --mkmaps`
- `initexmf --update-fndb`

Comment: The question is old, but the problem still present in 2021: this answer solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: No need to be condescending, BambOo. The question may be old, but the problem is still present in 2022, and the previously provided answer didn't resolve my problem, but this one did. Thanks Faten for providing it!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Then I simply search for the "pdftex.map" file, which was in my user profile, and deleted the file. After that, my latex worked again.