# Why will Beamer Equation Killing Document

Tags: beamer, equations

I am a totally new to beamer and I just can't seem to figure out why beamer won't let me include equations.  I run the following code and it does not work. I try to include {equation*} but it still does not work.  Any help would be appreciated

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Modified CAPM }

\begin{equation}%
\begin{split}
R-Rf& =\alpha_1EU+\alpha_2US+\beta_1MktRf+\beta_2EUFund*MktRf+\epsilon
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Also it does not work when I update the code to simply:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
R-Rf=\alpha_1EU+\alpha_2US+\beta_1MktRf+\beta_2EUFund*MktRf+\epsilon
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Everything is working here using TeXlive 2013 on Linux. Please, post the error message from the log file.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  For your information, adding four spaces before code will typeset the code properly in your question.  Alternately, highlight the code, and click the `{}` button in the window.  I have done this for you.

Comment: The errors include:  ! misplaced alignment tab character &.          !missing $ inserted          !missing $ inserted    0 pages are made

Comment: The above code also does not print pages

Comment: You can not use math without math mode. Use `equation` environment like you'd posted before. The code above requires `$...$` to type formulas.

Comment: So could you give me a bit more. I have tried multiple variations of interpreting your $...$ and it does not work.

Comment: Your original file is working fine for me on TeX Live 2012 on a Mac. Maybe you can remove all the .aux and other generated files, and try again from a clean folder with only the .tex file in it?

Comment: solved running C:\Pragram Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\updmap.exe, thanks @UlrikeFischer  Found on this page http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64147/beamer-over-miktex-2-9-is-not-working-with-math-environment

Answer (score 2):

solved running C:\Pragram Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\updmap.exe, thanks @UlrikeFischer
I found it eventually on this page-->
[beamer over miktex 2.9 is not working with math environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64147/beamer-over-miktex-2-9-is-not-working-with-math-environment)

Comment: On that basis, I'm marking as a dupe and asking Ulrike to post an answer on that other question.