# Why does a fatal error occur when I use math mode in a tabular environment in beamer?

Tags: tables, beamer, math-mode, errors

I am trying to create a table in a beamer class document which includes some entries in math mode. Below I provide a very minimal working example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
$n$ & $m$ \\ 
2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This code causes a fatal error to occur and no pdf file is produced. I am using texmaker with SumatraPDF.

Why does this code produce a fatal error?

Comment: Would be an idea to also list the exact error you get

Comment: Your example compiles just fine for me.  Are you copying a minimal working example that causes your error?

Comment: I do not get an error message, but at the end of the logs it appears: !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file mathkerncmssi10): Font mathkerncmssi10 at 657 not
found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: @Teepeemm, yes, this example gives me an error.

Comment: miktex? see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64147/beamer-over-miktex-2-9-is-not-working-with-math-environment

Comment: @David Carlisle, thank you, I managed to fix it by following some of those instructions.