# ArsClassica Error (rm-iwonar not found), Iwonar Package Installed

Tags: errors, miktex, windows

I'm trying to use the `arsclassica` package for my document, and have some problem. Here's the simplest form of the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,beramono,eulermath,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1 Test}
testing
\chapter{Chapter 2 Test}
testing
\end{document}
```

When I compile it with pdflatex, there's no resulting pdf, but I did found this error message on the log file:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file rm-iwonar): Font rm-iwonar at 657 not found
```

I can't figure out why the error occures, because I've installed the `iwonar` package, and I can't find a package called `rm-iwonar`. I am on Windows with MikTex if that's relevant. I've been googling around with no luck.

Deleting this line:

```
\usepackage{arsclassica}
```

make the document compiles fine. What's wrong with the document? Any additional information needed?

Thanks before.

Comment: You probably have a multi user installation. You have a local pdftex.map but did install the package as admin - this will not update the local map-file. Run on the command line `updmap`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I do have a multi user installation. Running `updmap` results in nothing though. How do I know about the local pdflatex.map?

Comment: Check the log-file. (And the map is called `pdftex.map`).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it's still the same error. I've fixed it by running `initexmf` first though, from this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22453/new-map-file-with-miktex thanks for the hint though :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @UlkireFischer's comment, I've search further and found [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22453/new-map-file-with-miktex). Turns out in a multi user environment we need to update the map file, using these command:

```
initexmf -u --verbose
updmap --verbose
```

Running these two commands fixed my problem instantly. Hope this helps.