# Adding Imprint Shadow font

Tags: fonts, packages, installing

I'm using MiKTeX on Windows, and I've found Imprint Shadow font which I'd like to use with lettrine for capitalization of first font of chapters (I'm experimenting a bit). I've extracted all the necessary files from [here](http://www.findthatzipfile.com/search-44272525-hZIP/winrar-winzip-download-imprintmtshadow-tds-zip.htm).

I also have the .pbf font in place. Now I don't understand the next step I've found in the [instructions](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/fonts/imprintmtshadow/imprintmtshadow.pdf):

```
3.  Add +miih.map to the configuration files of dvips, pdftex and your
    dvi previewer.

4.  Run texhash and updmap programs to update the conguration files and file names database
```

Where do I need to do this? :\ Do I need to just update formats and file names database in MiKTeX options?

EDIT: And even tho I've added everything as instructed (I unzipped everything in its right place) I cannot get the font to work :| Any help on this?

Comment: The link here is dead, and it's not clear what you did try in respect to the instructions you've included.

Comment: Well I am using `lettrine` to capitalize the first font in a chapter. And I thought that having Imprint Shadow font for a 'Big Letter' would look nice. Usually you can specify what font you want that first font to be, but I cannot seem to install the Imprint Shadow font correctly, even tho I have all the necessary files. 

Oh and I've updated the link.

Comment: Did you buy the font files themselves?

Comment: You mean .pbf .pfa and .ttf files? Yeah, I have them and I've put them in the right place, as in the instructions.

Comment: Does any of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22453/new-map-file-with-miktex help?

Comment: I'm on Windows 8 atm, and this seems to be Linux solutions (terminal). Can I do this in command prompt?

Comment: Without more feedback, I think this is a dupe of the link I've given: certainly unlikely to be progress without knowing if those steps were taken