# Font display error in windows

Tags: beamer, fonts

I encountered the following while trying to process my PDF document from LaTeX, MiKTeX 2.9

```
Trying to make PK font mathkerncmssi8 at 600DPI...

Running miktex-makemf.exe... 

miktex-makemf: The mathkerncmssi source file could not be found. Running tt2pk.exe...

make-makepk: PK font mathkerncmssi8 could not be created.
```

Process exited with errors

Answer (score 32):

This worked for me when I had a similar error.

Simply navigate to your miktex bin directory and execute the commands below:

- e.g.  c:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\
- `initexmf --mkmaps`
- `initexmf --update-fndb`

as described in: https://www.dev-eth0.de/blog/2016/11/13/latex_miktex-makepk-pk-font-umvs-could-not-be-created.html

Comment: The second command is properly `initexmf --update-fndb` Other than that, this is a perfect answer to this problem.

Comment: I required adding --admin to the commands, after initexmf

Answer (score 31):

This may be due to MiKTeX not having the `map` file activated.

Try adding the following to your document's preamble and see if it generates:

```
\usepackage{sansmathaccent}
\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}
```

If it works, then you should [update MiKTeX's font maps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28811/21920).