# Problem with the installation of libertinust1math package

Tags: packages, installing

I would like to use the Linux Libertine Font for my document; as suggested [here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/linuxlibertine/) I have inserted this 3 code lines in the preamble of the input file

```
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Compiling the code I obtained this error massage

```
File `libertinust1math.sty' not found.
```

I downloaded the package from [here](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/libertinust1math) and put the folder in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\libertinust1math
```

Finally, following what suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64133/sty-file-not-found), I refreshed FNDB as admin.
Now the error message is:

```
Font LS1/libertinust1math/m/n/10=libertinust1-mathrm at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. }]
```

Can someone help me to solve the problem? 
(I'm working on Windows10, with MikTeX 2.9 and TeXstudio)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is of the same kind as the one stated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133781/font-display-error-in-windows?lq=1), i.e. the `map` file of the font is not activated.

To solve this issue, open a command window and type the following:

```
initexmf --edit-config-file updmap
```

This will open the file `updmap.cfg` in a text editor window. Add the line

```
Map libertinust1math.map
```

to the file and save it.
Then run

```
initexmf --mkmaps
```

and everything should work as expected.

Comment: I tried with your suggestion, but now I obtain these messagges: `Running miktex-makemf.exe...` `miktex-makemf: The libertinust1-mathit source file could not be found. Running hbf2gf.exe...` `hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4) Couldn't find libertinust1-math.cfg' miktex-maketfm` `: No creation rule for font libertinust1-mathit.` before the usual error message posted above.

Comment: I'm afraid my knowledge concerning font installation is rather limited. If the solution above didn't work for you, I can't help you any further. `:-(`

Comment: thaks for your help anyway. I was wondering if my installation procedure (i.e. download the package and put it in the folder specified above) was correct. Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes any difference for MiKTeX's ability to find the files, but I'd suggest the following: download the `.zip` archive from the link you provided and place the contents of each of the archive's subfolders in the respective MiKTeX directory. E.g. place the contents of `afm` in `.../MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/afm`. `afm`, `enc`, `map`, `tfm` and `type1` all can be found under `.../fonts`.  You may place the contents of the archive's `tex` subfolder in a new folder `MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/libertinust1math` and those of the `doc` subfolder under `MikTeX 2.9/doc/latex/libertinust1math`.

Comment: Then refresh the FNDB. It can sometimes be helpful to do this twice: once "normally" and once as admin. After all that, you might have to again apply the solution in my answer above, though I'm not sure about that.

Comment: something changed in the error message `Trying to make PK font libertinust1-mathrm at 390 DPI... Running miktex-makemf.exe... miktex-makemf: The libertinust1-mathrm source file could not be found. miktex-makepk : The application file ttf2pk.exe could not be found.`

Comment: I can't think of anything else that could help you, sorry.

Comment: OK, don't worry. I noticed that my default compiler is PdfLaTex: it might be relevant...

Answer (score 1):

Are you willing to try it the LuaLaTeX way? Does not require much by way of learning. MWE:

```
% !TeX program = LuaLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} % Note the O
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\begin{document}
I detest math.\par
Math: $x$\par
\end{document}
```

The first two lines are meta-instructions to TeXWorks, which might not apply to your setup. Note that there is no call to the Libertine or Libertinus packages! Calling those packages is actually counter-productive, in this case. If the Open Type fonts *.otf are in your system and can be found, then they will be loaded without regard for any map files or metrics.